# Object not receiving message

Tags: game-engine

I have a game I am making, but I have run into a brick wall.  My player is not receiving any messages.  It uses Dynamic physics type and it is set to receive any message.  I want it to receive a message from a child circle below it.  They are both in the same scene.  I want the circle to tell the player that it is on the ground so the player can know when to jump.

The circle's script:
[image: Circle Script]

The player's script:
[image: Player Script]

Comment: You will have to add more info for us to help you. From what you described I can not tell you what went wrong. A screen shot of the logic bricks for the object that sends the massage, and the object that is so post to be getting the message would help a lot.

Comment: I agree with David. Does the sender exist in the running scene? (not all object types are supported e.g. curve). Is the sender in the same scene as the recipient? If not, do both scenes exist at the same time? Did you set up the "To:" field? If yes, ensure the object name matches the name of the recipient (or simply leave it blank). Have you setup a subject? Ensure the subject of the actuator and the sensor match (look for trailing spaces). The physics type is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

Possible cause: **combination with keyboard sensor**

Just as it is the configuration looks fine. But there is a danger.

You combine the message detection with keyboard detection. That means the actuator will only be activated when you hold the specified key  and receive a message at the same time.

It might be you want to activate the motion actuator when either the key is pressed or a message is received. In that case I suggest to replace the AND controller with an OR controller.

To analyze if the message can be received at all, you can disconnect the keyboard sensor (leaving the message sensor).

To analyze if the motion actuator has any effect on your object, you can disconnect the message sensor (leaving the keyboard sensor).

I hope it helps

Comment: I want the message to tell the player it can jump.  The keypress is there so the jumping is triggered, not automatic.

Answer (score 0):

Possible cause: **no collision**

This would result in never activating the message actuator = no message at all.

You can analyze this situation by connecting a different actuator that does something you can notice while running the game (e.g. turning the object via motion actuator, or counting a property that is shown in the debug overlay).

If that actuator does not show something your collision detection has a problem -> different question.

Otherwise this answer does not help you.

Comment: I've already tried the debug and the physics type is static w/ cylinder collision bounds.

Comment: Objects with Physics type "Static" do not detect collision (because they do not move in terms of physics). This reduces the calculation time a lot. Therefore your sensor never triggers the controller which never activates the actuator. Following objects can detect collisions: Character, Sensor, Soft body, Rigid Body, Dynamic.

Comment: Ok!  I'll try that!

Answer (score -1):

On your collision trigger, click the true level triggering (pulse mode) or the other gadget at the top left of the actuator. Same for if using the always.